# Azure and log4net - Remove process name

Tags: azure, logging, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I am trying to configure log4net for logging via Azure. However, once the logs make it to the storage the log source is attached to the log message-

**WorkerRole.WorkerRole**: Starting Role Test

I need an exact log format, however the log4net prepends **WorkerRole.WorkerRole:** to the message.

Here is the config I am using for the log4net setup-

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="TraceAppender" type="log4net.Appender.TraceAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <!-- can be any pattern you like -->
        <conversionPattern value="%message" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <!-- does not have to be at the root level -->
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="TraceAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across this same issue.

Looking at the Trace Appender in a debug session I could see that `TraceAppender.Category = "%logger"` which according to the [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/P_log4net_Appender_TraceAppender_Category.htm)

> Defaults to %logger which will use the logger name of the current LoggingEvent as the category parameter.

Further digging found [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-106) logged on the Log4Net bug tracking

> TraceAppender : Add switch to disable using logger name as trace category

The item is marked as fixed, although it isn't clear exactly what you add to the config file.  A bit of testing with some of the suggestions on the conversation thread found that you can just set the category to what you want, so if you don't want anything, then just add this to your config:

```
<category value="" />
```

Make sure it is a child of the `appender` tag, e.g.

```
<appender name="TraceAppender" type="log4net.Appender.TraceAppender">
  <category value="" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Alternatively I suppose you could try creating a new appender derived from `log4net.Appender.TraceAppender` and override the `Category` property to force it to your own value.

Comment: With this, log4net (1.2.13) still appears to emit a ": " prefix, is there really no way to turn the category off?

Comment: I didn't really look into it; I just accepted the ": " and moved on :) You could  look at creating your own appender class and try and override the base behaviour of [TraceAppender](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4net/trunk/src/Appender/TraceAppender.cs?view=markup) but suspect you may need to look at RenderLoggingEvent of [AppenderSkeleton](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4net/trunk/src/Appender/AppenderSkeleton.cs?view=markup)